# Using Parcel bundler over Jekyll output

Tags: jekyll, parceljs

I have a static site generated with Jekyll. I wanted to use Parcel Bundler on it to minify and auto rename css, js and image files easily. But when I run `parcel _site/index.html` in the root folder, I get this error:

```
/Users/muratcorlu/works/muratcorlu-net/_site: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Using `--log-level 5` also doesn't give extra information about this error. I couldn't find a way to debug this problem. Any idea?

Comment: I'd give it another try with parcel 2-beta. That solved many bumps in my case. Still i'm wondering how to set up a proper build chain that works hand in hand with the jekyll compiler.

Comment: I noticed that problem occurs because of directory references in urls or meta tags like `<a href="./">Home</a>`. I added `index.html` to those urls in templates like `<a href="./index.html">Home</a>`. This fixed most of the problems.

Comment: The suggestion from @MuratÇorlu helped me, but I also had to fix another problem: Directory names containing dots, such as "release-1.0.0" seem to be treated as files and cause the same error message. I replaced the dots with dashes and eventually resolved the EISDIR error.